# Internet trouble ubuntu 14.04, no upload speed

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet, upload

I'm new to Ubuntu and have some issues regarding my Wifi connection. I have searched this website for a fix, but nothing has helped (just did a fresh install). 
My wireless card is built in to my motherboard http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87IPRO

So the problem is, I can't access some internet pages, like facebook, my google account etc. But for example newspages and youtube works like a dream. I am not very experienced with Ubuntu, so I don't have a clue where to start.

This computer is running Winows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. I have no issues with my internet when I'm running windows.

I did a pingtest (pingtest.net) and had no packet loss what so ever. I also did a speedtest, and got a decent download speed, but absolutely no Upload speed... It tried to upload for a minute or so, before it displayed the message: Upload test error.

Sometimes none of the pages works at all, or get very slow...

Did the lsusb and lspci command in terminal and got the following output:

```
PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 1532:001f Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c326 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:17d0 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1142
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;) The specifications for your motherboard don't give the exact specifications for your WiFi, so could you go into a terminal [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb` and `lspci` and post the output on the bottom of your question?

Comment: thanks ;) I did the commands you told me to do and posted them in my original question. I really hope someone could help me find a solution for this issue, so I can start using ubuntu daily :)
Thanks!

Comment: You need someone with more qualcom experience then me, that's why I upvoted your question.